# Publish/Subscribe API design : Unsubscribe and Update

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, api-design

I was looking for a Publication/Subscription system that lets me modify a current subscription. I couldn't find any, so I figured I would build my own (in JavaScript).

I have basic methods for `publish` and `subscribe` as follow :

```
ps.publish(params, function(err, res) {
...
});

ps.subscribe(params, function(err, data) {
...
});
```

Now I want to add methods for  `unsubscribing` and `update`ing my subscriptions. Ie. if `subscribe` is CREATE, then `unsubscribe` would be DELETE and `update` would be PUT.

How should I design these APIs ?
Should `update` just be an `unsubscribe` followed by another `subscribe` ? How do I let the user choose which subscription ?

Also, I am planning to use the return value to return a `future`, since I find it a more elegant way to combine asynchronous calls, but I am not sure if this is the best option, I am still weighting it against a fluent API. For that reason, and unless I can choose clearly, I prefer not to use it for now.

`unsubscribe` seems to be the easy one, but I don't want to end up in the wrong place :

```
ps.subscribe(params, function(err, data) {
   ps.unsubscribe(data.id);
});
```

How should I structure these methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually subscribe function returns another function which you use to unsubscribe. You could return from subscribe a function which when called without any argument would unsubscribe, but when called with another function as an argument, would update subscription.

In code it would look like this.

```
ps.subscribe = function (params, callback) {
  ...
  return function (callback) {
    if (callback) {
      ...
      // update - replace with a new callback 
    } else {
      ...
      // cancel subscription
    }
  }
}

var changeSubscription = ps.subscribe(params, callback);
changeSubscription(anotherCallback); // update
changeSubscription(); // unsubscribe
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit (with code example) please ?

Comment: I see now. I will sit on this a bit, but I'm not completely sold on the concept.

Comment: Another option would be to return some token from subscribe method (something you can use to find this subscription in the collection where you store subscriptions) and later use this token to update or delete subscription.

Comment: Yes that was my initial idea too, but instead of returning it I did put it into the `data` argument of the callback. I mean, would you like to use a library like that ? I'm not sure why but it still feels a bit clumsy to me.

Comment: I would rather go with my first concept - from subscribe return a function which can be used to modify this subscription.

You could also return an object with two methods - one for modifying one for updating.

Comment: Well after sitting on it a bit, in my mind the return value is best left as a future. So I will probably return an `id` in the callback, and do the same in a `future`. I'll wait a bit to see if other suggestions turn up. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I see another problem with that now : if the client never receives a message, then he can also never unsubscribe (not a big deal), or modify it's subscription (that's a big deal).

Comment: User receives the token or method for modifying subscription when he calls subscribe, so he doesn't have to wait for the first message.